# How to remove the nth element from the end of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I know you can use the "array_pop" to remove the last element in the array. But if I wanted to remove the last 2 or 3 what would I do?

So how would I remove the last 2 elements in this array?

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_pop($stack);
print_r($stack);
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/array_splice) and specify the number of elements which you want to remove.

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_splice($stack, -2);
print_r($stack);
```

Output

Array

```
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
)
```

Comment: Correct function, but the second parameter is the starting offset--*not* the number of elements which is the third parameter. Use `array_splice($stack, -2)` to remove elements counting back from the end of the array.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) with a negative `length`:

```
function array_remove($array, $n) {
    return array_slice($array, 0, -$n);
}
```

Test:

```
print_r( array_remove($stack, 2) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
)
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to remove the last 2 elements of that array, you should use array_slice in this way:

$fruits = array_slice($stack, 0, -2);

Answer (score 1):

as the rhyme goes: pop twice, or array_slice!

In other words: http://php.net/array_slice

Comment: This does not alter the original array.

Comment: It does not. But I don't see an issue?

Comment: "So how would I *remove* the last 2 elements in this array?" [emphasis mine]

Comment: Owkee, so you need to assign it to the origional. That kind of hand-holding isn't worth the -1 I'd say, but good luck to you sir. Question isn't interesting enough for this discussion, now is it?

Comment: Not my -1, sir, but thanks for the well-wishes! The OP also asked in relation to `array_pop` which *does* alter the original array, and `array_splice` in another answer alters it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **array_pop()** twice. Run it like this:

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
array_pop($stack);
array_pop($stack);
print_r($stack);
?>
```

Output:

```
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
)
```

The return value of **array_pop()** is the element you just removed, *not the array*. So if you don't need that element anymore, simply call the function as many times as you need and move on.